# strong-pm http auth 401

Tags: node.js, strongloop

I've installed strong-pm on an AWS linux instance:

```
[root@box]# npm -g install strongloop strong-pm
[root@box]# sl-pm-install --http-auth user:pass --force --upstart 0.6 --set-env NODE_ENV=production
[root@box]# /sbin/initctl reload-configuration
[root@box]# /sbin/initctl restart strong-pm
strong-pm start/running, process 18171
```

When I attempt to check the status of strong-pm, I get a 401

```
[root@box]# slc ctl -C http://user:pass@localhost:8701
(node:18234) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
(node:18234) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
Command "status" on "http://user:pass@localhost:8701" failed with Error: Error: 401
```

Thoughts? I've reinstalled several times with different user/pass combinations (no special characters, the "admin:foobar" example from the docs, etc) and nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full reinstall fixed it. My working theory is that an initial password containing special characters irrevocably mucked up something.

Comment: You may have had to do a `stop`, `reload-configuration`, then `start` instead of `restsart`. When working on strong-pm's service installer, I found Upstart (especially 0.6) to be really finicky when dealing with changing service configurations.